# fprintf not working in wireshark source

Tags: c, file, debugging, ssl, wireshark

I am trying to make changes to the wireshark source code and I added the following code to the file: /epan/dissectors/packet-ssl-utils.c

```
f=fopen("keys.txt","a+"); 
fflush(f);
fprintf(f,"Test"); 
ssl_print_data("Client Write key",c_wk,ssl_session->cipher_suite.bits/8); 
ssl_print_data("Server Write key",s_wk,ssl_session->cipher_suite.bits/8);
fprintf(f,"%s %s",c_wk,s_wk);
 if(ssl_session->cipher_suite.block>1) {
 ssl_print_data("Client Write IV",c_iv,ssl_session->cipher_suite.block);
 ssl_print_data("Server Write IV",s_iv,ssl_session->cipher_suite.block); 
fprintf(f,"%s %s",c_iv,s_iv); } 
else { 
ssl_print_data("Client Write IV",c_iv,8); 
ssl_print_data("Server Write IV",s_iv,8); 
fprintf(f,"%s %s",c_iv,s_iv); } 
fflush(f); 
fclose(f);
```

I declared the FILE pointer as 'f' at the start of the function ssl_generate_keyring().
After multiple attempts of running the scripts

---

```
sudo ./configure
sudo make
sudo make install
```

I am still not able to print the data from these variables to a file. The file itself is not created.

Can anyone advise me on how to write these variables to a file ?

**Background:**
You must set export SSLKEYLOGFILE=/home/somefilename.txt in a terminal. Launch browser from terminal and then browse traffic.

Go to wire shark preferences and then set keylog file in protocol tab -> ssl tab

Comment: Any reason you `fflush` a newly opened file? And where is your error-checking? What does the debugger say? What does "I am still not able ..." mean?

Comment: After the fopen, add a `fprintf(stderr, "f=%p\n", f);` line. Does it display a sensible address, or 0, or nothing?

Comment: I hope you declared the `FILE` pointer as `*f` and not, as you say, `f`.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick: Why not use the debugger? And adding a proper **permanent** check with error handling is the way to go, not `printf` debugging.

Comment: You didn't test if `open` worked successfully, it may happen that the working directory of the process is protected.

Comment: @Olaf By all means, good error handling, with a Qt popup window, should be added in the fullness of time. But here's my thinking: since the OP's program is not getting a segv nor creating the file, I suspect the wrong program is being run, or the file is being created in the wrong directory. That's what I want to determine first.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick: Hmm, uses Wireshark QT? Anyway, this is C, not wure why you bring up a GUI framework here. A simple `exit(WHATEVER);` would be sufficient in the first place. But you completely missed the actual point: use a debugger for debugging.

Comment: @Olaf Yes, Wireshark uses Qt. You made two points, the second of which was to do proper error handling. And I completely agree. Shouldn't proper error handling in a GUI program ultimately use the GUI to communicate an error?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick: They are actually related and should be both used. One is a permanent measure (maybe expanded lateron), the other temporary to find out details.

Comment: Thank your for the feedback. I shall get back here with the results once I incorporate a better debugger

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès got me closer to the right direction. As he suggested, the working directory of wire shark was protected. The file was not being created in the directory and hence I could not write to the file.  As I changed directories the code and any other modifications starting working.

Comment: I am adding this as the answer below and resolve the thread. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wireshark directory is write protected and hence any modifications that I made to wireshark code could not be written to a file in the same directory.

@MarkPlotnick, @Olaf and @Jean-Bapiste all point towards the right direction and generally as a good practice one should write better debugging code with error handlers.